# Why can a JS object index assign both a key and a value?

Tags: javascript, object

For the following:

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  for (i in obj2) {
    if (!(i in obj1)) {
      obj1[i] = obj2[i];
    }
  }
  return obj1;
}

extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1); // --> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(obj2); // --> {b: 4, c: 3}
```

Why does obj2[i] assign the value and not the key? Shouldn't it assign the letter, as obj1[i] does?

Comment: What do you mean by "assign value, not key"?

Comment: `i` is the key, `obj2[i]` is the value.

Comment: @PiotrKocia So the function creates a new key/value pair in the object: (c: 3). It's created via the line obj1[i] = obj2[i]. Obj1[i] assigns "c" but obj2[i] assigns "3." Maybe "assigning" is the wrong way to think about it and that's what's tripping me up?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Your code copies properties from obj2 to obj1 if the property to be copied doesn't yet exist in obj1.

`for ... in` iterates over **keys**, so `i` in your example will have value `b` and then `c`.

When `i` has value `b`, your if clause will not execute because the property `b` is already in obj1. When `i` has value `c`, if clause will execute, so the line in it will look like this

```
obj1['c'] = obj2['c']; // Assign value of obj2['c'] to property 'c' in obj1
```

which is essentially

```
obj['c'] = 3; // Assign value 3 to property 'c' in obj1
```